# Why is this text being highlighted?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have every instance of highlighting that I can find turned off. Search is also not open or filled out. It has only been happening since the February 2024 update. If I edit any of the highlighted text it goes away and if I then "undo" the edit it stays un-highlighted. If I switch to another tab and then come back to this one and my cursor is in any of these words, the highlights come back again and they never leave until I edit any of the highlighted text again. It happens on a PHP page.

[image]

As you can see, in the settings, highlighting is turned off:

[image]

Comment: This is not a duplicate, voted to reopen.  This is a [bug in release 1.87](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206486), they have a fix but it's not released yet

Comment: @scottfrazer Thank you for showing me that link! ... and agreeing with me that this is NOT a duplicate, as I have "matching" highlighting turned off and it still happens (which is why it annoys me more than others). Good to know it will be fixed eventually.